# Restrictions for starting activity from BroadcastReceiver Android 12 (API 31)

Tags: c#, android, maui

I have `BroadcastReceiver` with the following code in `OnRecieve` method:

```cs
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
int notificationId = intent.GetIntExtra("notificationId", 0);
string action = intent.Action;
if (action == "Open")
{
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(SplashScreenActivity));
    startIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    context.StartActivity(startIntent);
}
manager.Cancel(notificationId);
```

And it works well before Android 12. Starting from it notification cancels but doesn't start SplashScreenActivity. I've already read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) and find out that I need to provide `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission to app. But it is not explain why this code works well (without permission) on Android 11 where restrictions are the same.

Can somebody explain this strange behavior?

Checked starting activity on Android 13 (API 33), Android 12 (API 31), Android 11 (API 30)

Comment: Did you try to start the `MainActivty` instead of the `SplashScreenActivity`? Since the Android 12, the [splash screen](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen) uses new api instead of the `SplashScreenActivity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current implementation is called a notification trampoline. 
Set the notification action pending intent to launch SplashScreenActivity instead of sending a broadcast.